# Merging .htaccess Documents - Wordpress and aMember

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, amember

How would one go about merging these two .htaccess files?  I keep triggering 500 errors.

- Each version works beautifully on its own.
- Amember .htaccess (1st) protects access I believe should be implemented first.
- Wordpress .htaccess (2nd) is needed for clean urls.

htaccess 1)

```
########### AMEMBER START #####################
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

## allow access for product #12        
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} amember_nr=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
RewriteCond /home/www/changed.tld/amember/data/new_rewrite/%1-12 -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]

## if user is not authorized, redirect to login page
# BrowserMatch "MSIE" force-no-vary
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://changed.tld/amember/plugins/protect/new_rewrite/login.php?v=-12&url=%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://changed.tld/amember/plugins/protect/new_rewrite/login.php?v=-12&url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
########### AMEMBER FINISH ####################
```

htaccess 2)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /localsearch/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /localsearch/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thinking was backwards.  Trick was to 'rewrite' the wp links first and then run the amember protect .htaccess next.  Below is what ended up working for me.  Specifically note the missing [L] in the last line of the WP rewrite.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /localsearch/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /localsearch/index.php 
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

########### AMEMBER START #####################
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

## allow access for product #12        
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} amember_nr=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
RewriteCond /home/www/changed.tld/amember/data/new_rewrite/%1-12 -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]

## if user is not authorized, redirect to login page
# BrowserMatch "MSIE" force-no-vary
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://changed.tld/amember/plugins/protect/new_rewrite/login.php?v=-12&url=%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://changed.tld/amember/plugins/protect/new_rewrite/login.php?v=-12&url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
########### AMEMBER FINISH ####################
```

Comment: @Puggan Se With low rep you have to wait few hours before accepting your own answer.

Comment: aha, didn't know that, never asked somthing myself yet

Comment: Had to wait 3 days.  Marked now. :)